# How to develop automatically missed call reply messenger iOS mobile application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, addressbook

Nowadays I am thinking about a mobile application (specially for iPhone) and trying to build it for personal use and of course will allow to others too. I want to develop such application, suppose I have iPhone device.

My iPhone get missed call in the absence of me and in that that case suppose I missed some urgent call and I really did not want to miss them. So that my device should have automatically sent messages to them all that I could not receive those calls in due to my absence and message would be like "I am unavailable right now, please call me back or wait for my call".

So all that was the idea of mine I want to develop such mobile application, I would keep each think in my mind like don't send unnecessary reply even not needed. I'll look to the UI part also. That's why I am studying `AddressBook` frame and all related tutorial, and gathering all required thing to go ahead. But before going ahead on coding part.

Comment: There is no API for detecting incoming calls or sending text messages without user intervention.

Comment: Ohhh my GOD, but still looking over some google search , well thanks for your generous reply thnaks buddy

Comment: @一二三 i am not bother about incoming calls i would focus on missed calls only. well will keep your suggestion in my mind and try to get out some result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't have any public (developer-accessible) API's that allow what you are trying to do (either sending a SMS or a voice mail response back to somebody saying "I'm not available" or "I will be available in 2 hours").

Nor would Apple likely allow an app like this onto the app store if you wanted to sell or make it available to other people aside from your personal device, as apps that interface with phone functionality may violate some countries' privacy laws, not to mention Apple's own privacy guidelines.

Comment: Michael Dautermann thanks a ton to you for your kind reply u r the man always be here to help everyone and giving +1 for the same and however i'll look over the google search what he suggest me even i failed still try to find out some way....Thanks again...